# Creating sub directory in nuxt 3 creating issue in fetching data in store

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

i created a sub directory in nuxt 3 project but then when i createa build file the project is not working it cannot access data from store .I am stuck

If someone has already encountered this issue and fixed it then please shed some light